# Unable to connect the android device to Windows 7

Tags: android, debugging, windows-7, usb, driver

I have the following configuration

1. Windows 7 Ultimate running on MacBookPro
2. Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-I9300) with cyanogenmod 10.2(stable)
3. Android SDK with eclipse

I tried so much but my eclipse is not detecting the phone for usb debugging of an android application. I already tried the following.

1. I enabled the USB debugging on phone
2. After I connect my phone through USB cable I can only charge the phone. But can't do any file transfer.
3. I installed the samsung kies lite and samsung kies 3 also. But no luck. Still cant detect.
4. In the device manager, under other devices, it lists my phone as usb device with name GT-I9300 with an yellow mark. I tried to update the driver and chose the google driver which comes with sdk. But it shows Windows could not find device driver software for your device.
5. I tried the commands "adb devices"  and "fastboot devices". But the list is blank.

Now I am out of options. Can anybody give me some idea where is the problem or how can i troubleshoot it step by step?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download Google usb driver in your SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Then update the driver with local file from `SDK_PATH/extras/google/usb_driver/`

[EDIT]

If you still have the problem do update driver like this:

- Choose `Let me pick from the list of device drivers on my computer`
- Click `Have disk`
- Browse for `SDK_PATH/extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf`
- Select Android ADB Interface and install.

Comment: yea. I downloaded and I have chosen the same in update driver dialog box. Still didn't work.

Comment: Choose `Let me pick from the list of device drivers on my computer`, then `Have disk` and browse for `SDK_PATH/extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf` select `Android ADB Interface` and install. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it. Hope it works for you as well.

1. Open the "Device Manager".
2. Expand the "Other Devices" and right click on the device below
3. Select the "Update drivers" option.
4. Then "Browse my computer for driver software" and choose "let me pick from list of device drivers from my computer".
5. Click the "have disk" button.
6. Pick the "android_winsub.inf" file from SDK driver.
7. Select "Android ADB Interface"

Then simply click ok and install it. Remember the "Other  Devices" option may get disappear after the completion of the process so check in the task bar there should be a USB icon showing the connectivity. That means it's working fine and you're good to go.